# router bind with redirect in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my RouteServiceProvider in boot method I have following code:

```
$router->bind('companies', function($id) {
        try {
            $company = \App\Company::findOrFail($id);
            return $company;
        } catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            return redirect()->back()
                            ->with('status', 'Company does not exists')
                            ->with('type', 'danger');
        }
```

but "redirect" doesnt work when Company with specified id is not find. How to fix it?

Comment: What's on the `storage/logs/laravel.log` ?

Comment: There is nothing, because there are no errors, it display page, but with no data, it looks that it no jumps to "catch" block

Comment: What's printed in the `returned company`? null or any values?

Comment: It returns null for all of company attributes

Answer (score 0):

It seems like try & catch is fine problem is probably related with redirect. Try using this:

```
Redirect::back()
->with('status', 'Company does not exists')
->with('type', 'danger');
```

And make sure that you have a page to go back before visiting this companies page.

Comment: this doesn work :( It always return non exist company, not redirect :(

Comment: @Matej could you please elaborate the scenario ? Where is the starting point ? Is this an API or is there an actual user with browser and goes to homepage and try to search a company ?

Comment: Try using `redirect()->back()->withErrors('Company does not exists');`

Answer (score 0):

According to the provided information, the following would work for you. But, theoretically your method is correct.

```
$company = \App\Company::findOrFail($id);
if(is_null($company)){
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Company does not exists')
    ->with('type', 'danger');
}
else{
    return $company;
}
```

As you had commented, if all attributes in company is null in the return value, you can try `is_null($company->id)` in the if condition instead. (Assuming that you have the primary key **id**).